# Can Indians with valid US visas travel to UAE and get a visa on arrival?

Tags: visas, usa, india, uae, visas-on-arrival

I am an Indian national/passport holder. I have a valid US visa. Is a visa granted on arrival to the UAE to Indians who have a valid US visa?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you can get a 14 day tourist visa with a possible 14 day extension as long as they meet the following requirements:

> As of 1 May 2017, Indian nationals holding a normal passport valid for
>   a minimum of six months from the arrival date, and a visit visa or
>   green card issued by the USA which is valid for a minimum of six
>   months, can obtain a visa on arrival for a maximum stay of 14 days for
>   a charge of AED120 (subject to change). They can apply to extend their
>   stay for an additional 14 days for AED250 (subject to change).

[Source](https://www.emirates.com/english/before-you-fly/visa-passport-information/uae-visas/)

Answer (score 0):

A visa of 14 days can be issues on arrival with a USA visit visa:

> As of 1 May 2017, Indian nationals holding a normal passport valid for a minimum of six months from the arrival date, and a visit visa or green card issued by the USA which is valid for a minimum of six months, can obtain a visa on arrival for a maximum stay of 14 days for a charge of AED120 (subject to change).

([Source](https://www.emirates.com/in/english/before-you-fly/visa-passport-information/uae-visas/))

On arrival proceed to the service counter:

> Indian passengers can then proceed to the Marhaba service counter to get their entry permit for a fee of Dh100 and Dh20 service charges, and continue on to the passport control.

([Source](https://m.economictimes.com/nri/visa-and-immigration/uae-to-give-visa-on-arrival-to-indian-passport-holders/articleshow/70257926.cms))

A extension can be issued by 14 days for an additional AED250 (subject to change).